# Error while running php bin/magento setup:upgrade in magento 2

Tags: magento2

When i try to upgrade the setup from the magento root folder in cmd, using

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

i get below error

> Autoload error: An abstract factory could not create an instance of magentosetup
>   consolecommandmoduleuninstallcommand(alias: Magento\Setup\Console\Command\Module
>   UninstallCommand).

Can anyone suggest what is the issue.?

Comment: Can you try clean var/* folders and run composer install?

Comment: clean all var/* folders?

Comment: yes, rm -rf {magento_root}/var/*

Comment: i get this error. http://pasted.co/0635cc8f can u please check

Comment: which  magento version do you use and how do you install it (git clone or composer install)?

Comment: i downloaded magento master setup from git

Comment: Please update you composer and try one more time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30343/discussion-between-kandy-and-manashvi-birla).

Comment: i updated the composer, but still the same error continues